# why cant i console.log this variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to console.log the arr variable. It doesn't seem to work when I place a simple console.log statement at the end of the function.

```
function oddNumbers() {
    var arr = [];
    var i=1;
    while(i<=50){
        if(i%2===1){
            arr.push(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code with the console.log in it? What do you get when you log?

Comment: 100% scoping issue because it's outside of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you clarify, I can't be 100% sure about what the problem is, but it sounds like a scope issue.  You declare the variable `arr` within your function, which means that you cannot access it outside of the function.

So if you tried to `console.log(arr)` outside of your function, you would cause an error.  However, since you return `arr` from your function, you can `console.log(oddNumbers())` to view `arr`.  See the snippet below:

```js
function oddNumbers() {
  var arr = [];
  //your code here 
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 50) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(oddNumbers())
```

If the issue was that you were calling `console.log(arr)` after the line: `return arr`, nothing would be logged because no code is being evaluated after a `return` is processed.  If that was the case, you would see something like the below snippet:

```js
function oddNumbers() {
  var arr = [];
  //your code here 
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 50) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
  console.log(oddNumbers())
}
```

Comment: or put the log in the function. Lets not assume how the OP is doing things.

Comment: You're right, they could have also been calling `console.log()` after they have already returned `arr`